# Play framework on tomcat+lighttpd - jpa

Tags: playframework

Can you please advise what is wrong here. This is how my method in the controller class looks like

```
public static void save(Long jobId, Long posetByUserId)  throws Exception
{
    try{ 
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();  
        SavedJob job = SavedJob.findByUserIdJobId(connectedUserID(), jobId);  //place 1
        String validationText = null;

        if(job != null){          //place 2
            validationText = play.i18n.Messages.get("saved.already");
            renderJSON(validationText);
        }else{

            SavedJob saveJob = new SavedJob();
            saveJob.userID = connectedUserID();
            saveJob.jobId = jobId;
            saveJob.insertDate = date;
            saveJob.updateDate = date;
            saveJob.posetByUserId = posetByUserId;
            saveJob.message = play.i18n.Messages.get("save.saved");

            UserProfile userProfile = connectedUser();
            userProfile.arlSavedJobs.add(saveJob);
            UserProfile.saveUser(userProfile);
                    .....
            }
.......
}
```

I call the above method using AJAX.

Case 1
When I run play in development mode(not tomcat) and specify the thread pool as 1 all works well.

Case 2 
I deployed this to tomcat +lighttpd. The above method fails.

If I call the above method twice it seems like the first request is at "place 1" above in the mean time  second request reached "place 2"  and gives an error that "saved.already". The request are not serialized.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here but can you please advise. I need both the requests to save the two items.

Thanks for help.

I am still trying to debug further. Apologies if I mislead, it seems like the problem is down to hibernate trying to do a insert instead of update.

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update 
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96) 
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) 
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275) 

hibernate tries to fire an insert for an already saved entiry instead of an update
```

So for case 2 below : I send 2 requests. 
Request 1 gets saved down and now I have one object in userProfile.arlSavedJobs.add(saveJob);
Request 2 comes so should result into 1 insert and 1 update but I can see hibernate tries to fire two inserts and gives unique constraint exception. Any ideas?

Please note UserProfile.saveUser(userProfile); performs a merge on userprofile. After merge it calls an insert instead of update for already saved entity..?

---

Sure much appreciated. 
After investigation this is where I am at: When the first request comes it adds the object to the list at this place: userProfile.arlSavedJobs.add(saveJob); A save works fine. When the second request comes now this list "arlSavedJobs" already have a object and second request adds one more object to the same list. 
When it reaches inle "UserProfile.saveUser(userProfile);" and tries to save it, it should fire 1 insert for new object and 1 update for already existing object(added by request 1). However it fires 2 inserts for  both the objects and gives a unique constraint exception. The stack tracke is as follows:

[2012-02-23 23:37:39,914]DEBUG 21530[http-8080-3] - org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger.logStatement(SQLStatementLogger.java:111) - insert into SAVED_JOB (DELETE_FLAG, INSERT_DATE, POSTED_BY_USER_ID, UPDATE_DATE, JOB_ID, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[2012-02-23 23:37:39,967]DEBUG 21583[http-8080-3] - org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger.logStatement(SQLStatementLogger.java:111) - insert into SAVED_JOB (DELETE_FLAG, INSERT_DATE, POSTED_BY_USER_ID, UPDATE_DATE, JOB_ID, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[2012-02-23 23:37:40,019]ERROR 21635[http-8080-3] - org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:234) - Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
[2012-02-23 23:37:40,075]ERROR 21691[http-8080-3] - org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
        at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:47)
        at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:184)
        at models.UserProfile.saveUser(UserProfile.java:401)
        at controllers.JTLeadsController.saveLead(JTLeadsController.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.execute(ServletWrapper.java:540)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.run(ServletWrapper.java:531)
        at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:67)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2018)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
        ... 37 more
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:798)
        at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:47)
        at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:184)
        at models.UserProfile.saveUser(UserProfile.java:401)
        at controllers.JTLeadsController.saveLead(JTLeadsController.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)

Comment: it's really unclear what the problem is... it looks totally normal to reach "place 2" if you hit save twice with the same parameters! And what do you mean by  `gives an error that "saved.already"`? the code there is trying to retrieve a translation string... what is the error exactly?!

Comment: Thanks Stefano. The error is that it says :org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)  hibernate tries to fire an insert for an already saved entiry instead of an update.

Comment: That helps, but not enough :) . In your error message you should get the exact line number raising the error from your code. Could you post the remaining relevant part of the error message, and mark the corresponding line numbers in your code?

Comment: Just edited the original post with the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three places of possible errors:

- place 1: This method call ( SavedJob job = SavedJob.findByUserIdJobId(connectedUserID(), jobId);  //place 1 ) returns null although there is already a SavedJob available. You have to check the code that is creating the query.
- place 2: On your client side, you're firing the ajax event twice (e.g. by adding multiple onclick handlers to a button, or by not disabling the button after the first click so that a double click would fire it twice) ... that means, that your method is also executed twice.. however, under normal circumstances, it should find the job  and return the validation message. If however,
- place 3: You're using a database that does not support transactions. A normal database (mysql, postgresql, oracle, db2, etc.) would internally serialize the inserts and your code should work just perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Dorn. I can confirm that point 1 and 2 is not a problem. the method call at point 1 does give the object back. point 2 the call is fine as well. I have tried to print out the keys of the objects for the two requests just before the save and the keys are different(unique). I am using mysql. One thing that if I send request 1& 2 in a gap of 4-5 secs then it works fine. If I send the two request almost immediately somehow hibernate can;t figure out the old object is already saved and does an insert instead of update.When I save "UserProfile.saveUser(userProfile);" I perform a merge.

Comment: hmm... try to only save the job, not the userprofile as well. Check how you have configured cascading of saves/merges etc. .. it looks like thats an issue here.

Comment: saving only job works. saving parent should have worked but now sure why. Thanks for help.